# How to point at single values within top 10 % Excel VBA function

Tags: vba, excel, max

I have a column in excel full of numbers, like this:

```
   1
A  100
B  200
C  300
D  400
E  500
F  600
G  700
H  800
I  900
J  1000
K  1100
etc
etc
```

I formatted the column with a macro so that it highlights the top 10 %. Unfortunately, I have to work with it now, as in I have to have a piece of code that says: ok, grab the first cell that is in the top 10 % (say it's K1). Get K1 and copy it somewhere else.

Question:
How do I point to an element in the top 10 %? How do I tell VBA "Grab the first top 10% value (K1), then grab that second top 10% value?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have any code? Do you just want to copy the top 10 values from each column to another location?

Comment: Yes but individually. Because I will apply if statements to each of these top 10 values. For instance: If top 10 value x >500, do this. If top 10 value y <500, do that. You get what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Top 10% of values from each Column to a different Worksheet

```
Sub ProcessColumns()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, rowCount As Long
    Dim minvalue As Double, largeValue As Double
    Dim arr

    With Worksheets("Source")
        arr = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value

        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)

            minvalue = WorksheetFunction.Percentile(.Columns(j), 0.9)
            For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
                largeValue = WorksheetFunction.Large(.Columns(j), i - 1)
                If largeValue >= minvalue Then
                    arr(i, j) = largeValue
                    rowCount = i
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End With
    Worksheets("Target").Range("A1").Resize(rowCount, UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: trust me, I usually do, and my VBA file is probably 10 pages long. But this particular one I didnt know how to code at all. Anyway thanks for that, I'll try it out now